# This expression has type int list but an expression was expected of type unit

Tags: ocaml, read-eval-print-loop, toplevel, utop

I tried this in utop but since I am not familar with a dune project, it failed and report the error

> This expression has type int list but an expression was expected of type unit.

This is for the line `filter greaterthanfive list1`

```ml
open Base

let rec filter p inputList = match inputList with
    [] -> []
    | x::xs -> if p x then x::filter p xs else filter p xs
;;

let greaterthanfive num =
  if num>5 then true else false;;

let () = 
    let list1 = [1;6;8;3] in
    filter greaterthanfive list1
;;
```

Comment: Incidentally, `if expr then true else false` can be conveniently rewritten `expr`.

Answer (score 3):

`let () = <expr>` means `<expr>` is expected to evaluate to `()`

More generally, this construct has the form `let <pattern> = <expr>`, where `<pattern>` is anything you can put in the branch of a `match` expression. And `()`  is a literal pattern that will only match this value, which is also the only value of the type  `unit`.

In program code it is good practice to use `let () = <expr>` for the main part of the program to make sure it evaluates to `()` and indicates it will only have side-effects, such as printing to the terminal or writing to a file.

In  `utop` however, you usually want the value of an expression to be sent to  `utop`  to be printed, and in that case `let () = <expr>` prevents that. Instead you should just evaluate the expression directly.